# Create lazy minting website

Tags: nft, lazy-mint

How can we build a lazy minting website? We want to create a webpage which allow user to attach a file and then mint. The minted file will show in the marketplace.

I found this [tutorial](https://nftschool.dev/tutorial/lazy-minting/#redeeming-a-voucher-on-chain), but I don't know how to run it, found [this](https://medium.com/rarible-dao/nft-minting-vs-lazy-minting-mining-explained-4330dd57a4c4) but Rarible API not found as I posted [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/140817/404-in-rarible-protocol-api).

I'm totally lost.

Here my contract

```
contract NFTMinter is ERC721 {
    using Counters for Counters.Counter;
    Counters.Counter private _tokenIds;

    constructor(string memory tokenName, string memory symbol) ERC721(tokenName, symbol) {
        _setBaseURI("ipfs://");
    }

    function mintToken(address owner, string memory metadataURI)
    public
    returns (uint256)
    {
        _tokenIds.increment();

        uint256 id = _tokenIds.current();
        _safeMint(owner, id);
        _setTokenURI(id, metadataURI);

        return id;
    }
}
```

For lazy minting

```
contract LazyNFT is ERC721URIStorage, EIP712, AccessControl {
  bytes32 public constant MINTER_ROLE = keccak256("MINTER_ROLE");
  string private constant SIGNING_DOMAIN = "LazyNFT-Voucher";
  string private constant SIGNATURE_VERSION = "1";

  mapping (address => uint256) pendingWithdrawals;

  constructor(address payable minter)
    ERC721("LazyNFT", "LAZ") 
    EIP712(SIGNING_DOMAIN, SIGNATURE_VERSION) {
      _setupRole(MINTER_ROLE, minter);
    }

  /// @notice Represents an un-minted NFT, which has not yet been recorded into the blockchain. A signed voucher can be redeemed for a real NFT using the redeem function.
  struct NFTVoucher {
    /// @notice The id of the token to be redeemed. Must be unique - if another token with this ID already exists, the redeem function will revert.
    uint256 tokenId;

    /// @notice The minimum price (in wei) that the NFT creator is willing to accept for the initial sale of this NFT.
    uint256 minPrice;

    /// @notice The metadata URI to associate with this token.
    string uri;

    /// @notice the EIP-712 signature of all other fields in the NFTVoucher struct. For a voucher to be valid, it must be signed by an account with the MINTER_ROLE.
    bytes signature;
  }


  /// @notice Redeems an NFTVoucher for an actual NFT, creating it in the process.
  /// @param redeemer The address of the account which will receive the NFT upon success.
  /// @param voucher A signed NFTVoucher that describes the NFT to be redeemed.
  function redeem(address redeemer, NFTVoucher calldata voucher) public payable returns (uint256) {
    // make sure signature is valid and get the address of the signer
    address signer = _verify(voucher);

    // make sure that the signer is authorized to mint NFTs
    require(hasRole(MINTER_ROLE, signer), "Signature invalid or unauthorized");

    // make sure that the redeemer is paying enough to cover the buyer's cost
    require(msg.value >= voucher.minPrice, "Insufficient funds to redeem");

    // first assign the token to the signer, to establish provenance on-chain
    _mint(signer, voucher.tokenId);
    _setTokenURI(voucher.tokenId, voucher.uri);
    
    // transfer the token to the redeemer
    _transfer(signer, redeemer, voucher.tokenId);

    // record payment to signer's withdrawal balance
    pendingWithdrawals[signer] += msg.value;

    return voucher.tokenId;
  }

  /// @notice Transfers all pending withdrawal balance to the caller. Reverts if the caller is not an authorized minter.
  function withdraw() public {
    require(hasRole(MINTER_ROLE, msg.sender), "Only authorized minters can withdraw");
    
    // IMPORTANT: casting msg.sender to a payable address is only safe if ALL members of the minter role are payable addresses.
    address payable receiver = payable(msg.sender);

    uint amount = pendingWithdrawals[receiver];
    // zero account before transfer to prevent re-entrancy attack
    pendingWithdrawals[receiver] = 0;
    receiver.transfer(amount);
  }

  /// @notice Retuns the amount of Ether available to the caller to withdraw.
  function availableToWithdraw() public view returns (uint256) {
    return pendingWithdrawals[msg.sender];
  }

  /// @notice Returns a hash of the given NFTVoucher, prepared using EIP712 typed data hashing rules.
  /// @param voucher An NFTVoucher to hash.
  function _hash(NFTVoucher calldata voucher) internal view returns (bytes32) {
    return _hashTypedDataV4(keccak256(abi.encode(
      keccak256("NFTVoucher(uint256 tokenId,uint256 minPrice,string uri)"),
      voucher.tokenId,
      voucher.minPrice,
      keccak256(bytes(voucher.uri))
    )));
  }

  /// @notice Returns the chain id of the current blockchain.
  /// @dev This is used to workaround an issue with ganache returning different values from the on-chain chainid() function and
  ///  the eth_chainId RPC method. See https://github.com/protocol/nft-website/issues/121 for context.
  function getChainID() external view returns (uint256) {
    uint256 id;
    assembly {
        id := chainid()
    }
    return id;
  }

  /// @notice Verifies the signature for a given NFTVoucher, returning the address of the signer.
  /// @dev Will revert if the signature is invalid. Does not verify that the signer is authorized to mint NFTs.
  /// @param voucher An NFTVoucher describing an unminted NFT.
  function _verify(NFTVoucher calldata voucher) internal view returns (address) {
    bytes32 digest = _hash(voucher);
    return ECDSA.recover(digest, voucher.signature);
  }

  function supportsInterface(bytes4 interfaceId) public view virtual override (AccessControl, ERC721) returns (bool) {
    return ERC721.supportsInterface(interfaceId) || AccessControl.supportsInterface(interfaceId);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lazy minting means that the contract owner doesn't mint the tokens themselves. A dApp would call a `mint()` function that will mint new tokens.

There are a number of ways to call this function from the dApp (which I think is what you're asking for).

You would use a library such as [Ethers](https://docs.ethers.org) or [web3js](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-call) to call the blockchain.

```js
myContract.methods.mint().call({from: '0xabc....'})
.then(function(result){
    console.log(result)
});
```

First, you'd have to connect to a wallet (such as MetaMask or Rainbow), and set up the smart contract using the ABI. But that's mostly off-topic for this question.

Comment: can I use this? https://nftschool.dev/tutorial/lazy-minting/#creating-a-signed-voucher

Comment: You could, but using signatures could be overkill depending on the project, since you then need a server as well

Comment: I have updated my post. How should I implement lazy minting in NFTMinter contract?

Comment: If you want an answer for voucher-based minting, you should let us know in your question. Otherwise, my answer applies to a pure lazy minting contract, without vouchers.

Answer (score 0):

in fact, you used "Meta-Transaction" in this code, but what is mean? in this [link](https://medium.com/coinmonks/ethereum-meta-transactions-101-de7f91884a06) says :

"Meta Transactions are transactions who’s data is created and signed off-chain by one person and executed by another person who pays the gas fees."

in your scenario, you can get Token's information from users and sign them in backend and after selling them anyone can mint them(after verifying).

in summery in voucher base contracts we have 3 elements:

1- struct
2-hashing function
3-verifying function

here is your struct:

```
 struct NFTVoucher {
   uint256 tokenId;
   uint256 minPrice;
   string uri;
   bytes signature;}
```

and here is your hashing function:

```
function _hash(NFTVoucher calldata voucher) internal view returns (bytes32) {
return _hashTypedDataV4(keccak256(abi.encode(
  keccak256("NFTVoucher(uint256 tokenId,uint256 minPrice,string uri)"),
  voucher.tokenId,
  voucher.minPrice,
  keccak256(bytes(voucher.uri))
)));}
```

and here is your verifying function:

```
function _verify(NFTVoucher calldata voucher) internal view returns (address) {
bytes32 digest = _hash(voucher);
return ECDSA.recover(digest, voucher.signature);}
```

you can deploy smart contracts and test them. at first I recommend deploying and testing your contract locally for faster and better practice of meta transaction and vouchers and after that interaction with Rarible

Comment: in my deploy.js, I call NFTMinter like this `const yourContract = await deploy("NFTMinter", ["NFTExample", "E2ENFT"])`..now just change to "LazyNFT"?

Comment: the name must be the same as your smart contract name.

Comment: My question is how should I implement lazy minting in NFTMinter contract?